# How to draw a single point (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I´m making an app that draw lines between points to make a figure. The first thing is to draw points using touches but i´ve tried a lot and i still can´t find the way to draw the points firstly. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var xpoint: CGFloat = 0
    var ypoint: CGFloat = 0
    var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
            xpoint = location.x
            ypoint = location.y
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, you just need to take that location and add a view there. Try to update `touchesBegan` to look something like this:

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        xpoint = location.x
        ypoint = location.y

        //Initialize the view at the correct spot
        //We set the view's frame by giving it an origin (that's the CGPoint we build from the x and y coordinates) and giving it a size, which can be anything really
        let pointView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xpoint, y: ypoint), size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))

        //Round the view's corners so that it is a circle, not a square
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5

        //Give the view a background color (in this case, blue)
        view.backgroundColor = .blue

        //Add the view as a subview of the current view controller's view
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```